# Extjs 4.1 - How to create item in initComponent function

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a panel like

```
 var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 300,
        myValue:5,
        title: 'Filters',
        initComponent: function() {
            this.items = [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                value: this.myValue
            }];
            this.callParent();
        }
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

i try to create a item has `xtype: 'textfield'` and value is `myValue` of panel. But that's fail.

How to do that thanks.
Here is my example text **http://jsfiddle.net/4Cmuk/**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `Ext.create()` function which is used to create instance of your class. `initComponent` method can be used while defining the class using `Ext.define()` function, I am not sure but `initComponent` function would not work using `Ext.create()` method.

For e.g. See below code, it will get execute:

```
Ext.define('customPanel', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 300,
        myValue:5,
        title: 'Filters',
        initComponent: function() {
            this.items = [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                value: this.myValue
            }];
            this.callParent(arguments);
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    }); 

Ext.create('customPanel');
```